# How to instantiate a class only once, which is accessible by multiple ProcessPoolExecutor processes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, class, multiprocessing, locking

Is it even possible to create a single instance of a class and use ProcessPoolExecutor to access that single instance from multiple processes? Or will ProcessPoolExecutor ALWAYS instantiate a copy of the class for every process, even if the class is created outside of main() ?

Am trying to load a single Tensorflow savedmodel (as a class), which can then be utilised / accessed by multiple processes which generate complex instances/minibatches, from ProcessPoolExecutor, with returned results compiled into a single dictionary item.

My problem is that the function which generates the minibatches to be submitted to the model (evaluateSingleCycle) is processing intensive and the instances are large. So using multiple processes is most efficient to submit minibatches to the Tensorflow model. I have tried to use Lock to allow each process to access the Tensorflow model.
A single model class is required (it is c. +4GB, with a single GPU) so cannot be instantiated more than once. But the speed requirements mean that ProcessPoolExecutor, rather than ThreadPoolExecutor, is needed for the function which is feeding minibatches to the model.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import numpy as np
import random
from multiprocessing import Lock

'''
Problem -   Trying to create a SINGLE class for a SINGLE tf model, 
            which is then utilised by multiple processes from 
            ProcessPoolExecutor (via Lock-Acquire-Release), 
            with each process returning a tensorflow dot.predict
            inference 
'''

NUM_WORKERS = 8  # Dummy variable assignments
tInfo_M = {}
modKeyx = 'specificmodelname'
tInfo_M[modKeyx] = []
CYCAVAIL = np.arange(100)
STATES = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


class DDQN:
    def __init__(self, savedModel):
        self.savedModelName = savedModel
        print(f'Only want to __init__ {self.savedModelName} FIRST time, here MULTIPLE')
        self.instanceList = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
        self.lock = Lock()

    def get_qs(self, instances):
        batchQvals = self.instanceList[random.choice(instances)]
        # print(batchQvals)
        return batchQvals


def evaluateSingleCycle(c):
    anEval = []
    for _ in np.arange(30_000):
        ANOTHERMODEL.lock.acquire()
        batchQvalArrayINITIAL = ANOTHERMODEL.get_qs(c)
        ANOTHERMODEL.lock.release()
        anEval.append(batchQvalArrayINITIAL)
    return anEval


def main():
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_WORKERS - 1) as executor:
    # with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_WORKERS - 1) as executor:

        results = [executor.submit(evaluateSingleCycle, STATES) for cyc in CYCAVAIL]

        for f in cf.as_completed(results):  # faster? whatever results are completed first
            for aT in f.result():
                tInfo_M[modKeyx].append(aT)

    # print(tInfo_M[modKeyx])
    print(len(tInfo_M[modKeyx]))


# This is UGLY...
ANOTHERMODEL = DDQN(modKeyx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The tensorflow model is stripped out of the attached code, and the functions are simplified. It is a problem of using ProcessPoolExecutor to access a SINGLE instance of the class DDQN. I have tried numerous configurations, global ANOTHERMODEL, ThreadPoolExecutor (runs with single DDQN class instance, but only with 1CPU core (2 threads) so is very slow.
Running the code with ProcessPoolExecutor instantiates the DDQN class x NUM_WORKERS times...
Creating ANOTHERMODEL outside of main() and if **name** is just ugly...

So, a single instance of the DDQN class and using ProcessPoolExecutor...Is it even possible?
(I am using a Threadripper 2950X)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your posted class definition of `DDQN` that would require a single, sharable object or locking across all processes since no attributes are being modified. I also do not see where attributes `saveModelName` and `instanceList` are even referenced. Also, if the entire definition of `DDQN.get_qs` is a *critical section* (whose execution is serialized), what then is the point of using multiprocessing? I will assume that all of this is an artifact of your having greatly simplified the code to create a minimal, reproducible example.

If you need to share an object across multiple processes, then you can create a *managed* class from your original `DDQN` class. A manager process will be created and the single, managed object will reside in that process's address space. Method calls made to that object are actually being operated on a special *proxy* object, which will then send the call's details over to the manager process using *pickle* for execution and return the results.

```py
import concurrent.futures as cf
import numpy as np
import random
# Note we now only need a multithreading lock:
from threading import Lock
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class DDQN:
    def __init__(self, savedModel):
        # Attributes will not be exposed, only methods,
        # using the default proxy created by the manager.
        # Therefore, the locking logic is moved to this class, where
        # it probably belongs anyway.
        self.savedModelName = savedModel
        self.instanceList = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
        self.lock = Lock()

    def get_qs(self, instances):
        with self.lock:
            batchQvals = self.instanceList[random.choice(instances)]
            # print(batchQvals)
            return batchQvals

modKeyx = 'specificmodelname'

def DDQN_factory():
    return DDQN(modKeyx)

class DDQN_Manager(BaseManager):
    pass

DDQN_Manager.register('DDQN', DDQN_factory)


def evaluateSingleCycle(ddqn, c):
    anEval = []
    for _ in np.arange(30_000):
        # Locking logic moved to DDQN class:
        batchQvalArrayINITIAL = ddqn.get_qs(c)
        anEval.append(batchQvalArrayINITIAL)
    return anEval


def main():
    NUM_WORKERS = 8  # Dummy variable assignments
    tInfo_M = {modKeyx: []}
    CYCAVAIL = np.arange(100)
    STATES = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    with DDQN_Manager() as manager:
        ddqn = manager.DDQN()

        with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_WORKERS - 1) as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(evaluateSingleCycle, ddqn, STATES) for cyc in CYCAVAIL]

            for f in cf.as_completed(results):  # faster? whatever results are completed first
                for aT in f.result():
                    tInfo_M[modKeyx].append(aT)

        # print(tInfo_M[modKeyx])
        print(len(tInfo_M[modKeyx]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The entire DDQN class (as a single instanciation) must be locked so that it is accessible by only a single process at a time. The self.instanceList is the tensorflow model, and a single minibatch from an evaluateSingleCycle process can be submitted to it at any time (hence the lock). The model is not being modified but used for inference. I was thinking that IO from the multiprocessed evaluateSingleCycle was what reqd serialization in and out of the multiprocessing processes, not the get_qs. I must think about your proposed soln. It is slower than ThreadPoolExecutor in my original.

Comment: My comment re multiprocessing / serialization is wrong I think. But still unclear why that is relevant here, when sending instances from the discrete processors to the single locked DDQN model.

Comment: Multiprocessing and shared, managed objects have overhead. Only use if `get_qs` requires sufficient CPU such that what is gained by running tasks in parallel more than offsets that additional overhead.